# NSMutableArray keeps overwriting itself and only returning one entry

Tags: objective-c

The for loop that I am writing keeps overwriting itself and I need to be able to return all values. How do I keep my for loop from overwriting itself?

```
sourceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *file in sourceFiles) {


    NSString *sourceFile = [sourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:sourceFile];
    NSImageRep *rep = [[image representations] objectAtIndex:0];

    sourceArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                        sourceFile.lastPathComponent, @"fileName",
                                                        [NSNumber numberWithLong:rep.pixelsWide], @"width",
                                                        [NSNumber numberWithLong:rep.pixelsHigh], @"height",
                                                        nil], nil];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:` replaces the array on each trip through the loop.  Instead...

```
// prettier using modern clang literals...
NSDictionary *d = @{ @"fileName": sourceFile.lastPathComponent, 
                     @"width":    @(rep.pixelsWide),
                     @"height":   @(rep.pixelsHeight) };

// just add to the array we allocated outside the loop
[sourceArray addObject:[d mutableCopy]];
```

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thanks!